# How to detect if selected text is wrapped in span tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple `contenteditable` `div` that serves an editor, and a button with an `onclick` function that changes the color of selected text to be yellow.

```
    function yellow(){
    {       
        var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.color = "yellow";
        span.appendChild(selectedText);
        selection.insertNode(span);
    }
    }
```

I recently noticed that if I selected text OUTSIDE of my `div`, it could still be colored yellow (since I'm using `window.getSelection()`).

To fix this I added an if statement:

```
    function yellow(){
    {       
        var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        if(window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.id != "editor1") return;
        var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.color = "yellow";
        span.appendChild(selectedText);
        selection.insertNode(span);
    }
    }
```

I'm looking to add another if statement similar to this:

```
if(window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.id != "editor1") return;
```

except instead of `id != "editor1"`, it detects whether the selected text has span text wrapped around it or not.

Comment: Why are you using double curly braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.tagName === 'SPAN')`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61329546/670839 and just replace `A` with `SPAN`. It follows the same logic.