# Check if selection contains link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, execcommand

I am creating a rich text editor and I would like to use the same button to link and unlink selections.

`document.execCommand('createLink'...)` and `document.execCommand('unlink'...)` allow users to link and unlink `window.getSelection().toString()`.

However, there are no inbuilt methods to determine whether a selection is linked or not in the first place, so my question is: **How can you check whether or not a selection is linked?**

I have tried using `document.queryCommandState('createLink')` and `document.queryCommandState('unlink')`, but both queries always return `false`, even though, for example, `document.queryCommandState('bold')` works properly.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? or is it vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro vanilla JS

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro well, i thought of one way of doing it. i can cache the selection and then search the body of text for anchor tags and modify it that way

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro even doing it that way, though, you're going to run into the same issue which you would run into if you tried to make a rich text editor from scratch, and that is: if there's any duplicate combinations of words or letters or whatever -- how do you know you're modifying the correct one?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro so, i found a piece of code that works well enough. i still don't entirely understand ranges. i was messing around with the range methods and apparently it counts white space in the HTML and will reset the range count to `0` if a character immediately follows a space. anyways, when you get a chance, take a look at the code and let me know what you think

Answer (score 2):

I found the following piece of code, which works well enough for the time being, kicking around on SO:

```
const isLink = () => {
  if (window.getSelection().toString !== '') {
    const selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    if (selection) {
      if (selection.startContainer.parentNode.tagName === 'A'
      || selection.endContainer.parentNode.tagName === 'A') {
        return [true, selection]
      } else { return false }
    } else { return false }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also may be able to retrieve the link HTML element and pass it to [Selection.containsNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode)

```
const linkHtmlElement = document.getElementById('yourId');
// should return true if your linkHtmlElement is selected
window.getSelection().containsNode(linkHtmlElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `anchorNode` and `focusNode` text nodes to see if they are `a` elements. More details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

```js
function isLink () {
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  const startA = selection.anchorNode.parentNode.tagName === 'A'
  const endA = selection.focusNode.parentNode.tagName === 'A'
  return startA || endA
}
```